# Show Select2 option as selected

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

```
 <?=
$form->field($model, 'contributors')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'initValueText' => '',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a Contributor ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['data2']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
    ],
])->label('Contributors');
?>
```

How to show selected value, now it shows id as a selected.
please anyone help me.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Sorry for late reply didn't notice you need to set the initial text for the select2 as you are using the ajax option so you should use the option `initValueText`. According to the docs

> `initValueText` : The text to displayed in Select2 widget for the
>   initial value. This is useful and applicable when you are using the
>   widget with ajax loaded data AND/OR you are not providing the data.
>   Check the ajax usage section for an example.

So you need to use it like below add this line inside your controller action and pass it to the view or add it inside the view before the `select2`

```
$contributorName = empty($model->contributors) ? '' : Contributors::findOne($model->contributors)->name;

<?=
$form->field($model, 'contributors')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'initValueText' => $contributorName, // set the initial display text
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a Contributor ...'],
     'data'=>yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Contributors::find()->all(),'id','name')
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['data2']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
    ],
])->label('Contributors');
?>
```

---

You need to provide the data option to the set of values from which the selected value would be shown you want the `text` to be shown instead of the `id`, provide the `data` options in form of an array with `key=>value` pairs.

Looking at your code you want to show the contributor `name` against the `id` in database table so you should use [`ArrayHelper:map()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#building-maps)  along with querying your `Contributors` model, see below and update your field names for the `Contributors` model/table inside the `ArrayHelper::map()`

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'contributors')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a Contributor ...'],
     'data'=>yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Contributors::find()->all(),'id','name')
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['data2']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (contributor_id) { return contributor_id.text; }'),
    ],
])->label('Contributors');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply but why i use data when i use ajax for contributor and append into it when user type.

by the way i have try this solution but not working.

Comment: it does not work in your case because you are providing `data` inside the `pluginOptions` which overrides the `data` set at widget level @Nageen

Comment: You should use [`processResults`](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) too

Comment: sorry @Nageen didnt noticed it, updated my answer hope it helps